# Delphi 5 build error: Required package not found error

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-5

I am compiling my project from the command line using dcc32 compiler. I am running into this error 'Required package X not found' 
But I do have the path all the files in X.* defined in windows path variable.
I am stuck at this error.
Any insight is appreciated much!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compiling, the compiled package - .dcp - is needed. It doesn't help if this file is in the Windows search path, the compiler has to be able to find it, in its library path or the project's search path.

Answer (score 2):

I've suffered many headaches with problems like this - can't say for sure this will help you, but certainly should point you in the right direction:

1) As far as I know, Windows path variable is not enough for the Delphi compiler - even though you're running from the command line. You need to check your Delphi environment options, project options, etc.

2) Even if your Delphi paths appear to be correctly configured, your dpr may be referencing units explicitely that are not found; or you may have packages installed originally on different (and perhaps missing) paths than what your now pointing to;

3) Old, out of date DCU's found on your project paths can cause mysterious problems...

4) Can you compile this project in the IDE? What happens when you try?

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much! The likely cause for my errors is your reason number 3. There were duplicate dcp's on my build path.